# How to make discord bot delete messages send by the bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have made a discord bot that adds people to queue by a command and then shows the queue. I dont want the channel to fill up with unfinished queues. So I want the bot to delete its own messages.

Example:

user says: !dips

Bot says: 1. User #this is message 1.

Another user says: !dips

Bot says: 1. User, 2. Another user.      #this is message 2.

Bot deletes now message 1. which is not needed anymore since the same information is in message 2.

Here is the python code I am working with.

```
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):

if message.content.lower() in list_of_commands:
    await message.channel.send(queue(arg1,arg2,arg3))
    #After sending new message here, it should delete the old message.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the message as a variable and then delete it later.

```py
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.lower() in list_of_commands:
        msg = await message.channel.send(queue(arg1,arg2,arg3))
        # do your stuff
        await msg.delete()
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to save the variable outside the on_message() function.   Is there a way to return the variable.

Comment: You could use a variable or a list in the global scope instead; and then using `global variable_name` at the start of the function, and then declaring the variable with the message value or appending it to the global list, you could use it in other functions

Comment: Now it works, thanks to you! Never saw global before but it was all I needed.